# Reload the page with a different address bar URL when the unser clicks on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that needs to load with a key as part of the URL, but this key has to be removed from the URL once the page has been loaded.

e.g.If the initia URL is http://localhost:1337/supplier/0AB3E8EA-D441-49D2-B467-165C11597F86 , it will change to http://localhost:1337/supplier

So now my issue is that if the user reloads the page it will reload http://localhost:1337/supplier and it will get a 404.

So Im trying to find out a way to append the Key back to URL before the page reloads and then once it has been loaded I remove the key again.

I have tried to change the `window.location.href` on `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){})` but it doesnt work :(

Please help :)
Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Could you save the key as a cookie, and recover it from there on reload?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page?rq=1

Comment: @RoryJaffe I dont think that's what im looking for. Thats for when you want to modify the URL without reloading the page, my issue is to modify the URL just before the user clicks on reload.

Comment: Do all the key handling on server may be using session;